# Is it possible to move keys of Rig Main Properties?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, timeline

I'm animating a character rigged with Riggify. 
I want to switch IK/FK between two poses. If I want to modify the timing, I drag the keys of my whole character but thoses keys seems impossible to select and drag in the timeline... Don't know why but it's very frustrating...

[image]

---

here is a non-cropped image but I don't have any hope this will help more. Who knows ?
[image]

Comment: Hi. I can understand wanting to crop a picture to highlight the part *you* think is relevant, but this may crop out parts that would give *us* a clue as to what is wrong (though that's not a guarantee).

Comment: Thank you to take time to answer. I don't know if my problem was clear enough, I'll try with other words. Is it possible to drag keys other than loc rot and scale on the timeline ? Because apparently the IK/FK switch can be keyed but impossible to move afterward.